# Cannot resolve WCF timeout error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am consistently getting the following error from my QA server:

> Message: { strMessage = Class: ShopProcessServiceClient  Method: Main  Error: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/RyderShopProcessService/ShopProcessService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.  InnerException: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)     at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)  Source: mscorlib  StackTrace:   Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound.ShopProcessService.IShopProcessService.GetCusts()     at Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound.ShopProcessService.ShopProcessServiceClient.GetCusts() in c:\Development\SMO_VS_2013\HHOutboundClient\SOASolutionA\Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound\Service References\ShopProcessService\Reference.cs:line 7698     at Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound.ShopProcessServiceClient.Main(String[] args) in c:\Development\SMO_VS_2013\HHOutboundClient\SOASolutionA\Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound\ShopProcessServiceClient.cs:line 399, strProject = Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound, strRemedyTktResponse = INC000000091594 }   Extended Properties:

While looking up the associated errors in the above text, they **all point to either increasing the send/receive timeout and or maxing out the data values being sent (like maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647")**. **I have done both and still cannot get around this error.**

The thing is that when I run the **same** application with the **same** settings from **within** Visual Studio, **no error occurs**. **It only occurs when running on our QA server**.

It always crashes when processing the same collection around 170,000 records or so. The next biggest one is around 50,000 records. It did make it past it once, but subsequent tries have failed.

The other thing in the error that interests me is the following:
**System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection**

Also worth noting is the fact that I had a command timeout (for the sql to execute, although after debugging, it takes only a couple of seconds) of 5 mins and when the 5 mins were up, the error occurred. When I took the command timeout out and left it at the default, it crashed at the default value time. This possibly tells me it is having trouble reading the data in the database.

**If somebody can inform me what else I might be able to change to get around this error, I would greatly appreciate it.**

Below is the pertinent **web.config file settings for my service**:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://999.999.99.999/RyderCommonServices/ContentManagementService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ContentManagementService"
        contract="ContentManagementService.ContentManagementService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_ContentManagementService" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="Ryder.ShopProcessService.SOA.ShopProcessService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Ryder.ShopProcessService.SOA.IShopProcessService" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding_IShopProcessService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <!--<add baseAddress="\\miavdeteoabweb\c$\inetpub\Dev\RyderShopProcessService" />-->
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsHttpBinding_IShopProcessService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="false" performanceCounters="All">
      <messageLogging logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logEntireMessage="true" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2147483647" maxMessagesToLog="500" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <!--<add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>-->
      <add scheme="https" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

**This is the pertinent app.config settings for my client:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsHttpBinding_IShopProcessService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IShopProcessService">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logEntireMessage="true" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2147483647" maxMessagesToLog="100" />
    </diagnostics>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://ryderfitest.velsol.com/RyderDataPortal/RyderService.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_RyderService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_RyderService" contract="HHOutBoundService.IRyderService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_RyderService" />
      <endpoint address="http://999.999.9.999/RyderShopProcessService/ShopProcessService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="WsHttpBinding_IShopProcessService"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding_IShopProcessService"
                contract="ShopProcessService.IShopProcessService" name="WsHttpBinding_IShopProcessService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WsHttpBinding_IShopProcessService">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="webhttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="BasicHttpBinding_RyderService">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Without the source code of the WCF itself, there's not much we can check. Can you do logging on the QA server? if possible, make a datadump of each record right before you send it on the client and right after you read it from the socket on the server. that can give you an idea if it might be an error in your datasource or just a timeout because it takes too long. My personal guess would be that your client app cannot keep the connection open long enough.

Comment: Logging on the QA server is not allowed... If my client app can't keep the connection open long enough, what WCF setting should I change and to what? Would it be the send/receive timeout settings? I have them at 30 mins now. What is the exact max send/receive timeout value I can set?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by updating the send/receive/open/close timeouts. See below.

```
<binding name="WsHttpBinding_IShopProcessService" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
          openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
```